# Supporting batch API requests in java play framework

Tags: java, playframework, api-design

I have a use case where the front-end may need to make more than one unrelated GET call to render some component.

I want to create a route to allow a series of unrelated REST API requests in a single call. All the individual calls can be run in parallel to save network overheads. This is similar to a feature by Salesforce's [composite API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm).

e.g.:

```
Request:
{
"request" : [{
    "method" : "GET",
    "url" : "/get/all/cats",
  },
  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "url" : "/get/all/dogs",
  }]
}
```

How to go about making such a feature in a Java play framework project?